# Conditional filter using Knex.js and SQL with multiple search criteria

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, knex.js

I have a database of items that my user needs to be able to search. They can apply different filters such as `category`, `searchTerm`, `itemType`.

I know how to apply each of these filters in a knex query, but am not sure how to combine them conditionally. E.g. in one case, the user inputs only searchTerm. So I do not want to filter by category or item type, but only searchTerm. However, I want to have only one knex function which conditionally adds extra clauses to the query.

Something like:

```
const getFilteredItems = (searchCriteria) => knex('items')
   // IF (searchCriteria.searchTerm)
  .where('items.itemName', 'like', `%${searchCriteria.searchTerm}%`)
  // IF (searchCriteria.itemType)
  .where('items.itemType', '=', searchCriteria.itemType)
  // IF (searchCriteria.category)
  .where('items.category', '=', searchCriteria.category)
```

But I am not sure how to conditionally append the extra `where` clauses to the knex query. Is there an elegant way to do this without writing raw SQL?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can conditionally build your query with the knex query builder:

```
const getFilteredItems = (searchCriteria) => knex('items')
  .where((qb) => {
    if (searchCriteria.searchTerm) {
      qb.where('items.itemName', 'like', `%${searchCriteria.searchTerm}%`);
    }

    if (searchCriteria.itemType) {
      qb.orWhere('items.itemType', '=', searchCriteria.itemType);
    }

    if (searchCriteria.category) {
      qb.orWhere('items.category', '=', searchCriteria.category);
    }
  });
```

You can also use `this` instead of accepting a querybuilder argument as in the example @abdulbarik gave, but I think it is less explicit.

Comment: Note that arrow functions use the parent function's `this`-binding. If you want to use `this` instead of accepting a QueryBuilder parameter, it has to be a regular function.

Answer (score 3):

You can try the following :

```
const getFilteredItems = (searchCriteria) => knex('items')
  .where('items.itemName', 'like', `%${searchCriteria.searchTerm || ''}%`)
  .where('items.itemType', 'like', `%${searchCriteria.itemType || ''}%`)
  .where('items.category', 'like', `%${searchCriteria.category || ''}%`)
```

If any parameter is missing or `undefined`, it will match the field to be like `'%%'` which effectively means, don't care about this parameter.

Comment: _which effectively means, don't care about this parameter_ or, in some cases, it will make your request slower, sometimes x times slower. Because "like" queries are one of the slowest, especially with leading `%` (without proper indexes).

Comment: also, it doesn't work well if `itemType` or `category` is an `INTEGER` (or DATETIME, or almost any non-string type). At least in Postgres (maybe MariaDB is not that strict)

Comment: IMO the @Gangstead answer (it is the accepted one) is a much more robust solution

Answer (score 1):

Try [orWhere](http://knexjs.org/#Builder-where) and update your query on this basis

```
const getFilteredItems = (searchCriteria) => knex('items')
   // IF (searchCriteria.searchTerm)
  .where('items.itemName', 'like', `%${searchCriteria.searchTerm}%`)
  // IF (searchCriteria.itemType)
  .orWhere('items.itemType', '=', searchCriteria.itemType)
  // IF (searchCriteria.category)
  .orWhere('items.category', '=', searchCriteria.category)
```

**Example**

```
knex('users').where(function() {
  this.where('id', 1).orWhere('id', '>', 10)
}).orWhere({name: 'Tester'})
```

Comment: try to avoid mixing `.where` and `.orWhere` at the same level of filtering. Otherwise one day "OR AND precedence" will become a really nice bug: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48148604/1115187

Answer (score 0):

You can make it simple from an async await function like this:

```
public async getFilteredItems(searchCriteria): Promise<any[]> {
    const table = 'items';
    const columns = ['itemName', 'itemType', 'category'];
    const qb = (query) => {
      for (const col of columns) {
        query.orWhere(`${table}.${col}`, 'like', `%${searchCriteria[col]}%`);
      }
    }
    return await knex(table).where(qb);
}
```