# WHERE CLAUSE multiple condition COMBINE AND OR in same Query NOT WORKING

Tags: sql

```
SELECT *
FROM users
where user_id!='1' AND fast_name LIKE '%asim%'
   OR last_name LIKE '%asim%' OR CONCAT(fast_name,' ',last_name) LIKE '%asim%'
```

user 1=asim
but he give me result asim why?
however i am using userid not equal to
and second thing is user_id must check and other condition are optional means only one condition accept with userid condition tell me what issue

Comment: `where user_id!='1' AND ( ... OR ... OR ...)`?

Comment: Read about [operators precedence](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/operator-precedence.html).

Comment: *Which* SQL implementation? Tag it, then we can mark this as the duplicate that inevitably exists/.

Comment: user_id=1 which is asim in otherwords i want data except those users which are not equal to userid but equal to search fastname or lastname or combine fastname.lastname so this query not working perfectly

Comment: Show example data, desired output, and current output. Anyway, the answer is simple and was already shown: the differing operator precedences of `and` and `or`, which you can of course circumvent using `(parentheses)` to enforce the required logic. Tag which DBMS you are using, then we can probably show you an existing topic that answers this comprehensively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use brackets arround the or part:

```
SELECT *
FROM users
where user_id!='1' AND (fast_name LIKE '%asim%'
   OR last_name LIKE '%asim%' OR CONCAT(fast_name,' ',last_name) LIKE '%asim%')
```

Comment: The check on the concatenated values seems redundant.

Comment: Right, I overlooked the prior line, due to overfamiliarity with my own style of whitespace I guess!